# Как отлаживать в Netbeans php-код, вызванный jQuery?

Tags: netbeans, отладка, openserver, xdebug

Есть связка NetBeans + XDebug + Open Server.

В php-файлах вызванных напрямую (index.php) или из php отладчик останавливается на точках останова. Если php вызван через jquery, то отладчик не останавливается на точках останова.
Вот **php.ini**:

```
[Xdebug]  
zend_extension="%sprogdir%/modules/php/%phpdriver%/ext/php_xdebug.dll"  
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"  
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"  
xdebug.remote_log = "var/log/xdebug.log"  
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"  
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

Как заставить отладчик останавливаться на php, вызванном посредством jQuery?

Comment: php, вызванный посредством jQuery? что это значит?

Comment: HTML:  
<input type="button" value="ВОЙТИ" id="login-submit"/>  
JS:  
    $('#login-submit').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/PhpForAJAX/login.php',
            success: function(data){alert(data)}
        })
    })    
Так вот на точке останова в /PhpForAJAX/login.php не останавливается Netbeans, как заставить останавливаться?

Comment: Вот отчет с xdebug.org:   
Xdebug installed: 2.4.0  
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler  
Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC11 - Architecture: x86  
Zend Server: no  
PHP Version: 5.6.12  
Zend API nr: 220131226  
PHP API nr: 20131226  
Debug Build: no  
Thread Safe Build: yes  
Configuration File Path: C:\Windows  
Configuration File: D:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.6\php.ini  
Extensions directory: d:\openserver\modules\php\PHP-5.6\ext